# Why should we do network call in ViewModel (Android)?

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, configuration, android-viewmodel

We use ViewModels for storing and manipulating data that is to be used by Views in Activity/Fragment - as data in ViewModel survives configuration change which helps us to retain UI state. It is one of the reasons we do network call operations in ViewModel, but is there any other reason we do network call operations in ViewModel?

I read somewhere that if we do network calls in ViewModels, the call does not happen again on configuration change? But I'm pretty sure API call is happening again in my Fragment on changing device orientation.

Comment: The reason is to `avoid` / `prevent` the same network call for the second time on configuration change. Also this is just a general pattern now to separate data, network & ui layer for better code readability. Your data should always survive configuration changes unless needed otherwise. For example: You wouldn't want to keep the user waiting until the data is fetched, loaded & some other computation is done after a config change.

Comment: @DarShan, why should we avoid same network calls on configuration change?

Comment: If the data/content that is fetched, loaded & then computated  is going to be same, then why not? As I said previously you can make a network call if you want if it is an explicit requirement or you have a different logic to implement on a config change.

Comment: @DarShan Let's say I have a function 'makeApiCall()',  to make API call, in my ViewModel. When my fragment loads this method is called (I call this method in onViewCreated() of Fragment) which fetches some data and I put the data in my UI. Now I change my device orientation. Will this function not be called again?

Comment: @SparshDutta, you can call your function in init method of viewmodel makeApiCall() to prevent second call due to onViewCreated method. And you can store api result into livedata.

Comment: @Bhuvnesh That's the info I was looking for. Please put it in answer - along with any other advantage of making API call in ViewModel - so that I can mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this problem you can call your function in init method of viewmodel makeApiCall() to prevent second call due to onViewCreated method. And you can store api result into livedata.

Alternatively, You can also use LiveData scope like this:

```
val makeApiCall: () -> LiveData<List<Data>> = {
    liveData {
        emit(repository.fetchData()) // API call
    }
}
```

Call makeApiCall lambda function from your onViewCreated, now API call will emit only one time and your live data will get observed in onViewCreated.

1. This is the one of the main advantage of viewmodel to prevent API call on orientation change.
2. Another advantage is, Suppose if you close the screen and now API call is no longer needed so, if you are using RxJava you need to cancel/dispose API call to release resource so you can perform it in onCleared method of viewModel irrespective of orientation change.

Or if you are using coroutine you can use LiveData scope and viewModel
scope no need to care about canceling coroutine. it's managed by self.

Answer (score 1):

We keep api hit in viewModel because of following reasons as per my practices
1)It reduces the coupling between Android components and non Android components
2)You can reuse the same ViewModel for some other screen as well
3) After fetching data you store that data in you liveData holder which can be used data to your UI on it's configuration change without making api hit